# imageView does not seem to resize properly

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, swift5, xcode12

I've recently been trying to expand on the swift course I've been taking. After learning the basics through the course I wanted to make a fun little app just test out the basics (i.e. progress bar linking, buttons, constraints, etc...) After making my very "classy" storyboard I and trying to apply the proper constraints I am running in to an issue with the little Ryu image. When I run my app just to see if the UI looks correctly the Ryu image does not say constrained within the imageView box. Instead it reverts to the actual image size and creates a mess. I've attached an image of what it looks like below.

Is there anyway to do set this up through the UI builder or will I need to make the needed adjustments programatically?

Any help on this is really appreciated, as I worry if I can't figure out something like this that seems easy I will not be able to grasp more advance concepts.

[ImageView scaling issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uculy.png)

Comment: You haven't constrained the image view height in any way. You have related the top and bottom to other views but autolayout will move things around to suit the intrinsic content size. You can constrain the image view height to a specific value or you could use an aspect ratio height to, say, the height of the containing view (a value of 1:3 would make the image 1/3 of the screen)

Comment: I agree with @PaulW11 - this isn't (yet) an issue with the image view, it's with constraints. My suggestion? Don't (for now) use a `UIImageView`. Just put a plain `UIView` where you want this image view. (An **no** not a `UILabel`!) Get the layout you want. Check it out in both portrait and landscape. (I personally don't use IB but some find constraints in IB easier.) Set background colors to all the views so you can actually *see* the layout. Once you have this working, change it `UIView` to a `UIImageView` - that's when you can tell is you have an issue with a property called `contentMode`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and suggestions @Paulw11 and dfd. I'm going to go ahead and give that a chat. I think since it is something I am trying to learn with I am going to simplify the layout too a bit more and try to get that work too.